# TextBox.IsFocused property?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I want to change a `textBox.text` only if it is not in focus. Example:

```
public void updateValue()
    {
        if (!this.valueTB.IsFocused)
            this.valueTB.Text = updatedValue.ToString();
    }
```

But the problem is that `this.valueTB.IsFocused` property changes only when it's actually focused but not when it's focused out.

Comment: Is this `updateValue` in your `valueTB.TextChanged` event handler?

Comment: --Is this updateValue in your valueTB.TextChanged event handler? - NO

Comment: Maybe you can explain a little bit more what it is you want to achieve and add some more context to the code.

Comment: method updateValue() will be called out of my userControl class in a cycled thread which updates the int updatedValue field every 500 mseconds. So i want textBox.text to not change when it is busy by user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you could take a bool value which tells you if the TB is focused or not:

```
    bool TBIsFocused = false;
    private void valueTB_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TBIsFocused = true;
    }

    private void valueTB_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TBIsFocused = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `IsFocused` property certainly changes its value when the TextBox gets or loses the focus.

But TextBox also provides the [GotFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.gotfocus%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [LostFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.lostfocus.aspx) events.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the textbox focus event [Lost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.lostfocus.aspx)

And [GotFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.gotfocus%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that `IsFocused` event gets fired only once when it gets the focus thats it and then it doesn't fire. I think you want it to fire this event continuous till `Textbox` has the focus. For that you have to keep on checking whether it has the focus or not at specific interval.

Answer (score 0):

Use only [`IsFocused`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.isfocused.aspx) propery:

```
public void updateValue()
{
     if((!tb.IsFocused) || (tb.IsFocused == false))
     {
          tb.Text = "The text was updated when I wasn't focused. Is't OK?";
     }
}
```